# In JavaFX, is an observableArrayList thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, thread-safety

I update a table by modifying an observable array list but now 2 threads might modify the observable array list. Should I place the code that modifies the list in a synchronized method or will only 1 thread be allowed to modify the list anyway?

Comment: If modifying your `ObservableList` changes your `TableView`, then you must only access it from the FX Apllication Thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344042/modifying-fxcollections-synchronizedobservablelist-out-of-the-ui-thread

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this particular use case - where the `ObservableList` is bound to a `TableView`, you must only access the list from the FX Application Thread. This is because changes to the list will result in changes to the `TableView`, and [all changes to the scene graph must occur on the FX Application Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

So in this case, the question as to whether the `ObservableList` is thread safe is a moot point: since you can only access it from a single thread for other reasons, you don't need it to be.

If you have a background thread that needs to update the list, you can schedule those updates to occur on the FX Application Thread by wrapping them in a call to [`Platform.runLater(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-), or (and this is probably preferable) by using the [`javafx.concurrent` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) to manage your threading.

Comment: Thanks for stopping me making a blunder! I need to use something like this private Task createTableLoaderTask() {
        Task<Collection<JobView>> tableLoader = new Task<Collection<JobView>>() {
            @Override
            protected Collection<JobView> call() throws Exception {
                return dao.retrieveAllJobs();
            }

        };
        tableLoader.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            Worker worker = event.getSource();
            jobData.addAll((Collection<JobView>) worker.getValue());
        });
        return tableLoader;
    }

Comment: Your `onSucceeded` handler can be simplified to `event -> jobData.addAll(tableLoader.getValue())` but yes, that looks correct.

Comment: The formatting didn't work too well! I was actually modifying the view by modifying the list in the background thread instead of just retrieving the data on the background thread and then updating the list on the UI thread by calling the setOnSucceeded method

Answer (score 4):

You can create a synchronized ObservableList from an ObservableList by calling

```
javafx.collectionsFXCollections.synchronizedObservableList(observableList)
```

This creates a wrapper for your observableList which you can use to add items to your list.

The question is what synchronization means to you. Because a technical synchronization does not necessarily mean that it is synchronized in terms of your business requirements, e.g. if you have to add 2 items by sequentially calling add(...) twice on the list and to assure that they are contained in sequence (with no other items in between). Maybe you have to ensure synchronization on a different level anyway.

Comment: Everything in this answer is true, but it's not really relevant to the case presented in the question. If the `ObservableList` is bound to a `TableView`, then you *must* only access it from a single thread (the FX Application Thread). Using a synchronized list, or adding your own synchronization, when you can only access it from one thread would be pretty pointless.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. Accessing the `ObservableList` only from the FX Application Thread can be achieved by creating a `Runnable r` calling `javafx.application.Platform.runLater(r)`.

Comment: Saw that you were stating the point `Platform.runLater` earlier already.

Answer (score 2):

No, implementation of `ObservableList` is just a wrapper that add listner method over the normal `List`(normal java collections)

so its not thread safe, you can go and see the source code of `ObservableListWrapper`.

more information : https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm